# Glade Gtk::TreeView::Column signal connect causes segmentation fault

Tags: treeview, gtkmm, glade

I have an application with a TreView designed in Glade. I need click in a column header in this TreView and perform some action. But when I connect the callback function the application crash with segmentation fault.

Bellow is the link for my code and glade file (it is a ZIP file!). When I comment out line 70 from **monitor.cpp** the problem disapear, but I am not able to perform the callbacks.

Another part of the code has the same behavior. Maybe I made the same mistake in both. See from line 129 from **monitor.cpp**.

[Monitor application](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nolvp9gvb94qhtz/monitor3.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Its better if your provide a minimum working example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hi @miltonb 
Now the code and glade file are even smaller as you have suggested. Just click the link!